# Spring Roo 2.0.RC1 - Entity Projecttion Elements with null values don't show in list

Tags: spring-roo

I have change the clinic example and add an entity projection for pets.

```
entity projection --class ~.domain.PetInfo --entity ~.domain.Pet --fields id,name,type,birthDay,owner --entityFormatExpression "#{name} (#{type})"
repository jpa --entity ~.domain.Pet --interface ~.repository.PetRepository --defaultReturnType ~.domain.PetInfo
```

I have remove all finder for Pets. The finder must change use PetInfo as return type -so i have remove them to test only  entity projection.

Before i have added  entity projection the list show all entries in Table Pets with and without set owner.

[image]

When i added entity projection in list only show items which have owner not null.

[image]

I use mysql db and change settings:

```
// Create the Spring Boot application
project setup --topLevelPackage org.springframework.roo.clinic --projectName clinic_new --java 8

// Setup the data access layer
// jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL --databaseName clinic --userName root --password
// --force funktioniert nicht also erst löschen un dann neu hinzufügen
property remove --key spring.datasource.url
property add --key spring.datasource.url --value jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/clinic --force
property add --key spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto --value update
property add --key spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect --value org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
property add --key spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy --value org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
property remove --key spring.messages.encoding
property add --key spring.messages.encoding --value UTF-8
property add --key spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql --value true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Roo generates the following code in the `PetRepositoryImpl_Roo_Jpa_Repository_Impl.aj` file:

```
JPQLQuery<Pet> query = from(pet);
[...]
return loadPage(query, pageable, Projections.constructor(PetInfo.class, pet.id, pet.name, pet.type, pet.owner ));
```

By default, the `loadPage` function will generate an `INNER JOIN` with the owner table, so only the pet elements that have relation with `Owner` will be showed.

To prevent that, you should make push-in of the `findAll` method and define a `leftJoin` statement.

```
JPQLQuery<Pet> query = from(pet).leftJoin(pet.owner);
```

With that, you should be able to obtain all the pets with relations and without relations.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Glad to hear that! Remember to up-vote the answer ;) Thanks!